# Custom user avatar for FCM React-Native iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am currently using @react-native-firebase/messaging for one of my projects and wanted to ask if anyone happens to know if you can add a custom user avatar (like the one in the picture)?

If you know how to do this with FCM or know any another libary that can do this, I would be very happy if you could help me!

[Example Notifaction from WhatsApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYOiG.jpg)